# Add tax free fees to WooCommerce cart programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I try to add fees based on some calculations I do on Woocommerce cart, but I want to exclude it from VAT. This is my code:

```
function woo_add_cart_fee( $cart ) {
    global $woocommerce; $bookable_total = 0; 

    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data'];

        //doing my stuff to calculate $fee variable

    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fees: ', $fee, false, '' );
    //WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fees: ', $fee, true, '' );
    //WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fees: ', $fee, false, 'zero rate' );
    //WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fees: ', $fee, true, 'zero rate' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

I have tried all the commented versions and each of them includes a VAT on Fees too.

Any idea how I can achieve it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I contacted also with woo commerce support and they told me that my initial code was correct and there is a possible conflict with the theme or another plugin. I will investigate it in Monday.

Answer (score 5):

*(**Update**)*: **TAX OPTIONS with  [add_fee() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)**

> **IMPORTANT:** The fact that TAX **is working or not** with [**`add_fee()` method**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) depends **first of your tax settings** in woocommerce. As you have **not tell** in your question **what are your TAX settings**, It's not possible to help you *(Tax settings can be much more different for each e-commerce web site)*.

**Particular case:** When using `add_fee()` method **to add a discount** *(with a negative amount)*, **the taxes are always applied**.

For example if you want to use **'zero rate' tax class**, but you haven't defined the correct 'zero rate' tax class for the customer country, this will not work if you try to use it with: 
[**`WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fees: ', $fee, true, 'zero rate' );`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)
… **depending on your global tax settings**.

Here is a screenshot of REAL checkout totals, for 3 items in cart (using the code below):

[image]

> **Class WC_Cart add_fee() method, adds additional fee to the cart.**

> ```
> add_fee( string $name, float $amount, boolean $taxable = false, string $tax_class = ''  )
> ```

> 

> ```
> Parameters:
> ```

```
    $name      Unique name for the fee. Multiple fees of the same name cannot be added.
    $amount    Fee amount.
    $taxable   (default: false) Is the fee taxable?
    $tax_class    (default: '') The tax class for the fee if taxable. A blank string is standard tax class.
```

---

**Original answer** *(updated code)*:

> **Your main problem is in** this line: **`global $woocommerce, $bookable_total = 0;`**

> 1. As you are using **`WC()->cart`** syntax instead of **`$woocommerce->cart`** syntax, **you don't really need `global $woocommerce;`**.
> 2. If you use **`global $bookable_total = 0;`** this **`$bookable_total`** will be **always** **`= 0`**.
>    Instead you will use **`global $bookable_total;`** **without a value** to get the value defined outside your function. 
>    But if you want to **set the value to zero**, in case is not defined outside your function, you will do it this way: **`woo_add_cart_fee( $bookable_total=0 )`**

We can defined now **`$bookable_total` variable value outside** the function.

**This is a working example with your code:**

```
// This variable value is passed to our function
$bookable_total = 1;

function woo_add_cart_fee( $bookable_total = 0 ) {
    global $bookable_total;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // just for this example
    $item_count = 0;
    $item_fee = 5;

    // going through each cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $values ) {
        $item = $values['data'];
        if ( empty( $item ) )
            break;
        // getting the cart item_id
        $item_id = $item->id;
        $item_count++;
        // your calculations
    }

    // We test $bookable_total value, defined to '1' outside our function
    // and to 'O' if not defined outside (in this case the fee will be '0')
    $fee = $item_count * $bookable_total * $item_fee;

    // add_fee method (TAX will NOT be applied here)
    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fees: ', $fee, false );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

**This code is tested and it works.** *It goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

If the **`$bookable_total` variable is not defined outside**, the value will be **`0`**.

> **Note:** is better to get the $items ids with: **`$item = $values['data']; $item_id = $item->id;`**

---

**Reference:**
[Class WC_Cart - **`add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable = false, $tax_class = '' )`** method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the detailed answer, but I believe there was a misunderstanding. `$bookable_total` was just a variable I use on the loop and it changes if there are specific product types. It doesn't affect the amount of fee. But, to be clear. My code add a fee, but it includes a Tax. I want to let the fee be tax_free. Which non of the 4 codes does.

Comment: @Tasos Ok I have updated my answer. Your problem is certainly related to your woocommerce website **Tax settings**...

Comment: @Tasos Precision: On my screenshot real example I am using (as a french customer) 20% of normal tax rate. So as you see tax is not applied to fee.