# WooCommerce - Make a set of coupons adding a fixed fee to an order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

A client has a very odd request: they would like for a set of coupon codes to **add a fee** to an the order. Is this possible?

The problem they are trying to solve is this:

Currently the store offers free shipping to the lower 48 United States, for which I have shipping classes and table rates properly configured. However, the coupons the customer has sold on a daily deal site are supposed to remove the free shipping benefit and add a fixed shipping fee.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it with that snippet code (for a set of coupons):

```
function coupon_add_cart_fee( $bookable_total = 0 ) {
    $has_coupon = false;

    // Set here your specials coupons slugs (one by line - last one have no coma)
    $coupon_codes = array (
        'your_coupon_code_slug1',
        'your_coupon_code_slug2',
        'your_coupon_code_slug3' 
    );

    // Set here your fee amount or make fees calculation (see the links in reference)
    $fee = 20;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // checking if that "special" coupon is applied to customer cart
    foreach ($coupon_codes as $coupon_code) {
        if ( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) {

            // If yes apply the fee to the cart
            if ( !$has_coupon ) {
                $has_coupon = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $has_coupon ) {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fees: ', $fee, false );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','coupon_add_cart_fee' );
```

**This code is tested and it works.** *It goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

---

> **TAX OPTIONS with  [add_fee() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)**
>
> **IMPORTANT:** The fact that TAX **is working or not** with [**`add_fee()` method**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) depends **first of your tax settings** in woocommerce.
>
> **Class WC_Cart add_fee() method, adds additional fee to the cart.**
>
> ```
> add_fee( string $name, float $amount, boolean $taxable = false, string $tax_class = ''  )> <!-- language: lang-css -->
>
> Parameters:
>     $name      Unique name for the fee. Multiple fees of the same name cannot be added.
>     $amount    Fee amount.
>     $taxable   (default: false) Is the fee taxable?
>     $tax_class    (default: '') The tax class for the fee if taxable. A blank string is standard tax class.
> ```

---

**Reference:**

- [Add tax free fees to WooCommerce cart programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894444/add-tax-free-fees-to-woocommerce-cart-programmatically/38902400#38902400)
- [Class WC_Cart - add_fee() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)
- [Class WC_Cart - has_discount() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_has_discount)

Comment: This looks fantastic and precisely what I need, @LoicTheAztec. This may be a more basic PHP matter that I am missing, but can I store an array of coupon code in the `$coupon_code` variable, since the fee needs to be added if any one of many codes are being utilized?

Comment: Tested perfectly with a single coupon value. Thanks for also helping with the array. Your help is much appreciated! Definitely learning a lot here.