# WooCommerce - Adding shipping fee for free user plan

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I am using WooCommerce and with [Paid Memberships Pro free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pmpro-aweber/).

On the web site we have 2 plans (a free plan and a paid plan):

- Free users can buy 1 item each month,
- Paid users can buy 4 items each months.

Now I don't know how to simply calculate shipping on checkout page with code like:

```
if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('2')) { // Paid plan

    //free shipping (0$)

} else {

    //add shipping 4$ to checkout

}
```

No shipping class, No region zone is affect shipping price.

I have tried to set Shipping options, but I can’t get rid of it.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 2.6+, shipping has been remodeled, and is quite complicated to customize it as you would like, without a plugin… Instead you do, is adding a fee based on your user levels and other conditions if needed.

Here is my code:

```
function add_shipping_fee( ) {

    // Set here your shipping fee amount
    $fee = 4;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('2') == false)
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping Fee:', 'your_theme_slug'), $fee, false );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','add_shipping_fee' );
```

*This goes naturally in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**This code is tested and working.**

---

References:

- [WooCommerce - Make a set of coupons adding a fixed fee to an order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927453/woocommerce-make-a-set-of-coupons-adding-a-fixed-fee-to-an-order/38927801#38927801)
- [WooCommerce class - WC_Cart - add_fee() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)