# Conditional progressive percentage discount based on cart item count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I would like to have a conditional progressive discount based on number of items in cart. After you added 2 products to the cart, you get a discount. More products you add and more discount you get.

For example:

- 1 product – full price (No Discount)
- 2 products – full price with 5% discount of the combined price
- 3 products – full price with 10% discount of the combined price
- 4 products – full price with 15% discount of the combined price
- *And so on …*

I have search over internet without any success. When searching about discounts I just fall on WooCommerce coupon feature or I get some old wrong code…

Any idea? How can I do it?

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like [Dynamic Pricing](https://woocommerce.com/products/dynamic-pricing/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Update - October 2018 *(code improved)*

Yes its possible to use a trick, to achieve this. Normally for discounts on cart we use in WooCommerce coupons. Here coupons are not appropriated. I will use here a negative conditional fee, **that becomes a discount**.

The calculation: 
— The item count is based on quantity by item and total of items in cart 
— The percent is 0.05 (5%) and  it grows with each additional item (as you asked) 
— We use the discounted subtotal (to avoid adding multiple collapsing discounts made by coupons)

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'cart_progressive_discount', 50, 1 );
function cart_progressive_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // For 1 item (quantity 1) we EXIT;
    if( $cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 1 )
        return;

    ## ------ Settings below ------- ##

    $percent = 5; // Percent rate: Progressive discount by steps of 5%
    $max_percentage = 50; // 50% (so for 10 items as 5 x 10 = 50)
    $discount_text = __( 'Quantity discount', 'woocommerce' ); // Discount Text

    ## ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ##

    $cart_items_count = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $cart_lines_total = $cart->get_subtotal() - $cart->get_discount_total();

    // Dynamic percentage calculation
    $percentage = $percent * ($cart_items_count - 1);

    // Progressive discount from 5% to 45% (Between 2 and 10 items)
    if( $percentage < $max_percentage ) {
        $discount_text .=  ' (' . $percentage . '%)';
        $discount = $cart_lines_total * $percentage / 100;
        $cart->add_fee( $discount_text, -$discount );
    }
    // Fixed discount at 50% (11 items and more)
    else {
        $discount_text .=  ' (' . $max_percentage . '%)';
        $discount = $cart_lines_total * $max_percentage / 100;
        $cart->add_fee( $discount_text, -$discount );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme.* Tested and works.

> When using FEE API for discounts (a negative fee), taxes are always applied.

---

**References:**

- [WooCommerce - Adding shipping fee for free user plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254267/woocommerce-adding-shipping-fee-for-free-user-plan/39254425#39254425)
- [WooCommerce - Make a set of coupons adding a fixed fee to an order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927453/woocommerce-make-a-set-of-coupons-adding-a-fixed-fee-to-an-order/38927801#38927801)
- [WooCommerce class - WC_Cart - add_fee() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly! :-) You saved my day.

Comment: this works, but woocommerce discourages negative fees. For a time they had blocked them, but too many people complained and the reverted back: github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13224

Comment: @Lane I know thanks anyway… For now, this just works fine and will continue to work since WC dev team will add a new method/class/functionality for discounts (out of coupons).