# WooCommerce cart discount from second item on regular items only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I found this piece of code on stackoverflow, it does what i need, except that i need to apply -5€ discount for each products right after 2 products are added in the cart.

Example:

- for 1 products in the cart the user will get 0€ discount
- for 2 products in the cart the user will get 5€ discount
- for 3 products in the cart the user will get 10€ discount
- for 4 products in the cart the user will get 15€ discount
- for 5 products in the cart the user will get 20€ discount

and so on...

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'custom_discount', 10, 1);
function custom_discount( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    // if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    // Only when there is 2 or more items in cart
    if( $cart->get_cart_contents_count() >= 2):

        // Initialising variable
        $is_on_sale = false;

        // Iterating through each item in cart
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            // Getting an instance of the product object
            $product =  $cart_item['data'];

            // If a cart item is on sale, $is_on_sale is true and we stop the loop
            if($product->is_on_sale()){
                $is_on_sale = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        ## Discount calculation ##
        // fixed reduction price
        $reduction = 5;


        ## Applied discount (no products on sale) ##
        if(!$is_on_sale )
            $cart->add_fee( '-5€ à partir du 2ème article commandé', -$reduction);

    endif;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better use the following that will count only regular items (not "on sale" items) and will apply a discount based on that specific count starting on the 2nd item:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'progressive_fixed_discount', 10, 1);
function progressive_fixed_discount( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    // if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Initialising variable
    $regular_items_count = -1;

    // Iterating through each item in cart
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

        // Count only on regular items (not "on sale" items)
        if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ){
            $regular_items_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    
    // Only for regular items starting on the 2nd item (not "on sale" items)
    if ( $regular_items_count > 0 ) {

        // Progressive fixed discount calculation on regular items only
        $discount = 5 * $regular_items_count;


        // Apply a discount for "on sale" items only 
        $cart->add_fee( __("-5€ à partir du 2ème article commandé", "woocommerce"), -$discount );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Some related [similar answers threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees+discount):

- [Quantity discount on 2nd item only in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266463/quantity-discount-on-2nd-item-only-in-woocommerce/54267265#54267265)
- [Custom discount for every NTH item in the cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333443/custom-discount-for-every-nth-item-in-the-cart/43333933#43333933)
- [WooCommerce: Add a discount based on individual items quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570692/woocommerce-add-a-discount-based-on-individual-items-quantity/43571682#43571682)

---

**Addition - Excluding a product category:**

> Replace:
>
> ```
> if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ){
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() && ! has_term( array( 5537 ), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
> ```

Comment: this works as a charm. I had tested the first answer first and it seemed to work except for the discount items

Comment: To exclude a product category: See at the end of this answer, I have made an addition for you ***(uptaded)***…

Answer (score 1):

You are so close. 
You know the number of items in cart `$cart->get_cart_contents_count()` and you want the discount to start after the first product.

Replace `$reduction = 5;`

with this `$reduction = 5*($cart->get_cart_contents_count() - 1);`

***Your full code should look like this:***

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'custom_discount', 10, 1);
function custom_discount( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    // if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    // Only when there is 2 or more items in cart
    if( $cart->get_cart_contents_count() >= 2):

        // Initialising variable
        $is_on_sale = false;

        // Iterating through each item in cart
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            // Getting an instance of the product object
            $product =  $cart_item['data'];

            // If a cart item is on sale, $is_on_sale is true and we stop the loop
            if($product->is_on_sale()){
                $is_on_sale = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        ## Discount calculation ##
        // fixed reduction price
        $reduction = 5*($cart->get_cart_contents_count() - 1);


        ## Applied discount (no products on sale) ##
        if(!$is_on_sale )
            $cart->add_fee( '-5€ à partir du 2ème article commandé', -$reduction);

    endif;
}
```