# WooCommerce - Adding Extra fee to Cart based on total items weight

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, cart

I need to add charge on product total weight and show it in cart.
I mean in cart, when adding an item, i will set an extra charge.

This charge should be calculate like this:

```
$extra_charge = $total_cart_weight * 0.15;
```

If it's possible, How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested my code? Is much better, low resource consumption and lightweight than a plugin. Thanks

Comment: yes, i tested. I dont Know knowledge about code so i need your help: my theme name is "santa" and cart wight is "$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight", how can i change this function to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily hooking this function to **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** hook, this way:

```
function weight_add_cart_fee() {

    // Set here your percentage
    $percentage = 0.15;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Get weight of all items in the cart
    $cart_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    // calculate the fee amount
    $fee = $cart_weight * $percentage;

    // If weight amount is not null, adds the fee calcualtion to cart
    if ( !empty( $cart_weight ) ) { 
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Extra charge (weight): ', 'your_theme_slug'), $fee, false );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','weight_add_cart_fee' );
```

**This code is tested and works**. It goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.

> **For tax options:** see [**add_fee() method tax options**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) depending on your global tax settings.

**Reference:**

- [Class WC_Cart - add_fee() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee)
- [Add tax free fees to WooCommerce cart programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894444/add-tax-free-fees-to-woocommerce-cart-programmatically/38902400#38902400)
- [WooCommerce - Make a set of coupons adding a fixed fee to an order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927453/woocommerce-make-a-set-of-coupons-adding-a-fixed-fee-to-an-order/38927801#38927801)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-extra-fee-option/) plugin to create an extra charge category. You may have to edit the plugin to make the % of cart fee a % of total weight fee but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out. I can't really edit the plugin for you unless I know where you are getting the weight from. You just have to edit the wc-extra-fee-option.php file and change line 133 so that $extra_fee_option_cost will be multiplied by the weight instead of $total. You can do this by putting the weight in a class and then calling the class on line 133. Alternatively you could make the weight a global variable and simply use that global variable in place of $total on line 133. Hope this helps!