# WooCommerce - Hide tax for user role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In our webshop we need to display prices without tax for companies, and with tax for persons. Both shall pay taxes, so we just need to change the view setting (woocommerce_tax_display_shop and woocommerce_tax_display_cart) based on user role (customer vs company).

We can't figure this out. Can anyone give us a hand?

Comment: have you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972780/disable-tax-programmatically-for-a-specific-user-role/39975559#39975559) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866674/role-based-taxes-in-woocommerce) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894444/add-tax-free-fees-to-woocommerce-cart-programmatically/38902400#38902400) so questions, may be this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

`pre_option_ + your option` will give you a name of the filter you can use to "temporarily alter a WordPress option before you display a specific view"

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_%28option_name%29

You will need to use the same for your cart option.

```
add_filter('pre_option_woocommerce_tax_display_shop', 'alter_tax_display');


function alter_tax_display( $tax_display ) {
    if (current_user_can("company")){
    return "excl";
  } else {
    return "incl";
}
```

Comment: Hi. This didn't work. First of all there is no function called get_current_user_role(). And it didn't work with this either: in_array( 'company', (array) $user->roles)

Comment: I edited the answer, you can try and use current_user_can("company") if that is your role.